# RestKit - RKObjectMapping only runs once

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios5, restkit

I'm using the RestKit iOS package to allow a user to pull info from an account they have. The code below works perfectly the first time through. However, if I attempt to use a different username and password a second time, it just loads the information from the first mapping call. Furthermore, when the request is sent the second time, it returns the data unreasonably quickly which leads me to believe it is just using cached data. I've searched high and low for any way to reset restkit (and its cache) and none of them have worked. Here's my code:

```
- (void)login {
    RKObjectMapping* mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[MyClass class]];
    [mapping mapKeyPathsToAttributes:
     @"Data.MailboxId", @"MailboxId",
     @"Data.value1", @"Value1",
     @"Data.value2", @"Value2",
     nil];


    [RKObjectManager objectManagerWithBaseURL:@"https://my.site.com"];

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.username = username.text;
    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.password = password.text;

    [[RKObjectManager sharedManager] loadObjectsAtResourcePath:@"/api/v1.0/?format=json" objectMapping:mapping delegate:self];
}
```

And here's my log from RestKit:

```
2012-01-30 11:59:40.413 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:265 Reachability observer changed for client <RKClient: 0x6f09640>, suspending queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x6f0a5d0 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=0 loadingCount=0/5> until reachability to host '0.0.0.0' can be determined
2012-01-30 11:59:40.425 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:389 Reachability to host '0.0.0.0' determined for client <RKClient: 0x6f09640>, unsuspending queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x6f0a5d0 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=1 loadingCount=0/5>
2012-01-30 11:59:40.436 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:362 Sending asynchronous GET request to URL https://my.hostednumbers.com/api/v1.0/Mailbox/?format=json.
2012-01-30 11:59:40.445 HostedNumbers[6909:707] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:310 Prepared GET URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest https://my.hostednumbers.com/api/v1.0/Mailbox/?format=json>'. HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
}. HTTP Body: .
2012-01-30 11:59:43.045 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:163 Asked if canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: with authenticationMethod = NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
2012-01-30 11:59:43.513 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:163 Asked if canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: with authenticationMethod = NSURLAuthenticationMethodHTTPDigest
2012-01-30 11:59:43.516 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:137 Received authentication challenge
2012-01-30 11:59:44.066 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:163 Asked if canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: with authenticationMethod = NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
2012-01-30 11:59:45.914 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:196 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 200
2012-01-30 11:59:45.917 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:197 Headers: {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 2733;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Mon, 30 Jan 2012 16:59:46 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache, no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/6.0";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "2.0.50727";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
}
2012-01-30 11:59:45.923 HostedNumbers[6909:707] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:202 Read response body: {"Data":[{"MailboxId":"SP6s2m5zgwze47lsN5bBew2","PhoneNumberList":[{"PhoneNumber":"1-877-564-7397","Description":"(877) 564-7397","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"F5MOV_sc3-f9xWcAOCC1Tg2"}],"PhoneNumber":"1-877-564-7397","Prefix":795,"Extension":4920,"ProductId":"_iFmgCPNtTuU1PlknnSqXQ2","ProductCode":"SAR","ProductDescription":"PATLive Messaging Executive","MailboxStatus":1,"BillingStatus":0,"MainMailbox":false,"InfoCode":0,"AliasId":"","FeatureGroupId":"hTw_mObs0ARWkbHxRXZyEw2","FeatureGroupDescription":"Hosted Voicemail/Fax","FeatureGroupIcon":"https://my.hostednumbers.com/images/services/SAR.jpg","ServiceName":"Hosted Voicemail/Fax","MailboxName":"Connor Grady 1","DID":true,"ExtensionDigits":0,"ParentMailboxId":"","NewMessages":4,"SavedMessages":2,"NewVoiceMessages":2,"SavedVoiceMessages":2,"NewFaxMessages":2,"SavedFaxMessages":0,"NewRecordings":0,"SavedRecordings":0},{"MailboxId":"vEqAb2JRNLrP1lB51FVkEw2","PhoneNumberList":[{"PhoneNumber":"1-850-523-3762","Description":"(850) 523-3762","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"T-Ykotn8UNweSr4O0jHiqw2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-330-3948","Description":"(888) 330-3948","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"KK41mHIFEo5jD9DrzG8_Ig2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-682-8469","Description":"(888) 682-8469","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"svD01yJqBrZuJK-HzKvpcQ2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-826-2674","Description":"(888) 826-2674","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"zUfxFyXxKXtHB9nMdCs5lg2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-853-4264","Description":"(888) 853-4264","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"vmMwo_7x2hYxKa4gAc0PpQ2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-856-2307","Description":"(888) 856-2307","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"ViDGc7pJW25kkimk-ObguA2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-856-2742","Description":"(888) 856-2742","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"Wpt7fnGXoz8RxcP-xZkl9g2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-858-8276","Description":"(888) 858-8276","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"hB-cyJHU-w4BcCVcXmcIsw2"}],"PhoneNumber":"1-850-523-3762","Prefix":795,"Extension":4613,"ProductId":"mLVv-rU2-6GRboN46onbOg2","ProductCode":"CTS","ProductDescription":"Call Tracker Service","MailboxStatus":1,"BillingStatus":0,"MainMailbox":false,"InfoCode":0,"AliasId":"","FeatureGroupId":"v1uO_bCjMNSP9mF90AlO4w2","FeatureGroupDescription":"Hosted Local","FeatureGroupIcon":"https://my.hostednumbers.com/images/services/CTS.jpg","ServiceName":"Hosted Local","MailboxName":"Connor Grady 2","DID":true,"ExtensionDigits":0,"ParentMailboxId":"","NewMessages":0,"SavedMessages":0,"NewVoiceMessages":0,"SavedVoiceMessages":0,"NewFaxMessages":0,"SavedFaxMessages":0,"NewRecordings":0,"SavedRecordings":0}],"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":"","DataInfo":{"TotalResults":2,"TotalPages":1,"CurrentPage":1,"ResultsPerPage":20}}
2012-01-30 11:59:45.956 HostedNumbers[6909:5e0f] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:210 Found directly configured object mapping, creating temporary mapping provider for keyPath '%@'
```

--My sign out happens here, the following is my second request with a username and password that should normally return with an authentication challenge--

```
2012-01-30 11:59:57.678 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:265 Reachability observer changed for client <RKClient: 0x6f14400>, suspending queue <RKRequestQueue: 0x6f145b0 name=(null) suspended=YES requestCount=0 loadingCount=0/5> until reachability to host '0.0.0.0' can be determined
2012-01-30 11:59:57.687 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKRequest.m:362 Sending asynchronous GET request to URL https://my.hostednumbers.com/api/v1.0/Mailbox/?format=json.
2012-01-30 11:59:57.691 HostedNumbers[6909:707] T restkit.network:RKRequest.m:310 Prepared GET URLRequest '<NSMutableURLRequest https://my.hostednumbers.com/api/v1.0/Mailbox/?format=json>'. HTTP Headers: {
    Accept = "application/json";
    "Content-Length" = 0;
}. HTTP Body: .
2012-01-30 11:59:57.698 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKClient.m:250 Reachability observer changed for RKClient <RKClient: 0x6f14400>, disposing of previous instance: <RKReachabilityObserver: 0x6f15cc0 host=0.0.0.0 isReachabilityDetermined=NO isMonitoringLocalWiFi=565500 reachabilityFlags=-- ------->
2012-01-30 12:00:00.012 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:163 Asked if canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace: with authenticationMethod = NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust
2012-01-30 12:00:02.076 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:196 NSHTTPURLResponse Status Code: 200
2012-01-30 12:00:02.082 HostedNumbers[6909:707] D restkit.network:RKResponse.m:197 Headers: {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 2733;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Mon, 30 Jan 2012 17:00:02 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache, no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/6.0";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "2.0.50727";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
}
2012-01-30 12:00:02.087 HostedNumbers[6909:707] T restkit.network:RKResponse.m:202 Read response body: {"Data":[{"MailboxId":"SP6s2m5zgwze47lsN5bBew2","PhoneNumberList":[{"PhoneNumber":"1-877-564-7397","Description":"(877) 564-7397","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"F5MOV_sc3-f9xWcAOCC1Tg2"}],"PhoneNumber":"1-877-564-7397","Prefix":795,"Extension":4920,"ProductId":"_iFmgCPNtTuU1PlknnSqXQ2","ProductCode":"SAR","ProductDescription":"PATLive Messaging Executive","MailboxStatus":1,"BillingStatus":0,"MainMailbox":false,"InfoCode":0,"AliasId":"","FeatureGroupId":"hTw_mObs0ARWkbHxRXZyEw2","FeatureGroupDescription":"Hosted Voicemail/Fax","FeatureGroupIcon":"https://my.hostednumbers.com/images/services/SAR.jpg","ServiceName":"Hosted Voicemail/Fax","MailboxName":"Connor Grady 1","DID":true,"ExtensionDigits":0,"ParentMailboxId":"","NewMessages":4,"SavedMessages":2,"NewVoiceMessages":2,"SavedVoiceMessages":2,"NewFaxMessages":2,"SavedFaxMessages":0,"NewRecordings":0,"SavedRecordings":0},{"MailboxId":"vEqAb2JRNLrP1lB51FVkEw2","PhoneNumberList":[{"PhoneNumber":"1-850-523-3762","Description":"(850) 523-3762","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"T-Ykotn8UNweSr4O0jHiqw2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-330-3948","Description":"(888) 330-3948","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"KK41mHIFEo5jD9DrzG8_Ig2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-682-8469","Description":"(888) 682-8469","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"svD01yJqBrZuJK-HzKvpcQ2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-826-2674","Description":"(888) 826-2674","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"zUfxFyXxKXtHB9nMdCs5lg2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-853-4264","Description":"(888) 853-4264","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"vmMwo_7x2hYxKa4gAc0PpQ2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-856-2307","Description":"(888) 856-2307","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"ViDGc7pJW25kkimk-ObguA2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-856-2742","Description":"(888) 856-2742","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"Wpt7fnGXoz8RxcP-xZkl9g2"},{"PhoneNumber":"1-888-858-8276","Description":"(888) 858-8276","Provisioned":true,"PhoneNumberId":"hB-cyJHU-w4BcCVcXmcIsw2"}],"PhoneNumber":"1-850-523-3762","Prefix":795,"Extension":4613,"ProductId":"mLVv-rU2-6GRboN46onbOg2","ProductCode":"CTS","ProductDescription":"Call Tracker Service","MailboxStatus":1,"BillingStatus":0,"MainMailbox":false,"InfoCode":0,"AliasId":"","FeatureGroupId":"v1uO_bCjMNSP9mF90AlO4w2","FeatureGroupDescription":"Hosted Local","FeatureGroupIcon":"https://my.hostednumbers.com/images/services/CTS.jpg","ServiceName":"Hosted Local","MailboxName":"Connor Grady 2","DID":true,"ExtensionDigits":0,"ParentMailboxId":"","NewMessages":0,"SavedMessages":0,"NewVoiceMessages":0,"SavedVoiceMessages":0,"NewFaxMessages":0,"SavedFaxMessages":0,"NewRecordings":0,"SavedRecordings":0}],"ErrorCode":0,"ErrorMessage":"","DataInfo":{"TotalResults":2,"TotalPages":1,"CurrentPage":1,"ResultsPerPage":20}}
2012-01-30 12:00:02.115 HostedNumbers[6909:3833] D restkit.network:RKObjectLoader.m:210 Found directly configured object mapping, creating temporary mapping provider for keyPath '%@'
```

Comment: Will you post the RestKit logs to verify whether the cache is to blame?

Comment: Added the RestKit logs to original post^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was surprisingly simple. I just added the following line of code to my request to force basic HTTP authentication and it all works:

```
[RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.authenticationType = RKRequestAuthenticationTypeHTTPBasic;
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing the cache policy ?

f.e.

```
RKClient* client = [RKClient clientWithBaseURL:APP_URL];
client.cachePolicy = RKRequestCachePolicyNone;
```

try it and see if this fixes your problem (temporarily).

Comment: I've added the following to my code:

    [RKObjectManager sharedManager].client.cachePolicy = RKRequestCachePolicyNone;

Unfortunately, the problem persists.